# Translate menu item made by view

Tags: views, 8

Question is simple, in the views module you can add a normal menu item. But when in the menu itself it can't be translated. Is there anyway to do this, or should I just add the menu item myself instead of letting the view do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After defining your menu item via views, you have to go back to the views list (/admin/structure/views). There is a "Translate" option under "Edit".

[image: views translation]

There, you can "Add" a translation, then choose your page display options and translate the menu item (applies for Drupal 8 only).

[image: views menu item translation]

If the menu item is not showing up, clear the caches (e.g. cache rebuild using `drush cr`).

Comment: For some reason my view is giving a fatal error when doing this. Might be because the original language got removed. Created a new view and tried with that one. Works perfect. So thanks

Comment: Ok i've fixed it by changing the configuration of the view, changing the original language. It's now working and not throwing fatal errors when translating.