# Unpublished taxonomy term keep showing in main menu and contextual filter

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I'am creating a Drupal 8 multilingual side, i have a main menu and a contextual filter that uses taxonomy term. in english version i wont translate all those taxonomy, so i dont want theim to be displayed on the menu neither on the contextual filter.

i've tried to uncheck the button "this translation is published" for the translation but the taxo keep showning on the site :/

[image]

Any help please?

Comment: Have you restricted your Views to only show results in the language you want? You haven't posted anything about your views and Contextual configuration, but the question seems to be about those. Can you add those in?

Comment: Yeah i already did that, the problem isn't with the results, because view returns only the interface current language.
The problem is with taxonomy contextual filter and the main menu (they return all taxonomy of current language ) and default language for untraslated taxonomy

Comment: The Contextual filter takes TID as argument, and terms translations have the same TID as the original term (the term and its translations all have the same TID). So the way to control Menu item visibility isn't through Views, but through the Menu system. How are your menu items created? What is your configuration for the Menu translations? https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/202411/translate-menu-item-made-by-view, https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/multilingual/menu-translation-in-drupal-8

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the thing that is i'am using taxonomie on my main menu, and some exposed filters in views.
i cant translate the taxonomie in the menu because its just get  the taxonomy link. so when i translate taxonomy and i switch to english .
the menu switch but the untraslated taxo keep showing also in the menu
same thing for contextual filter with taxonomie
I dont wanna show all taxo in my filter, i just wanna show translated ones

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding the Drupal’s multilingual will fall back to the default language, meaning that if a translation is not available, the asset will be shown or rendered in the default language. I don’t think there is a workaround for that.